# Understanding the gauge condition in light-cone gauge

Tags: string-theory, gauge, ghosts

When going over [Cambridge String Theory Notes](http://scholar.harvard.edu/files/yshi/files/_st.notes_.2014_new.pdf) (page 38) I came across the following gauge conditions:

$$X^+ (t, \sigma) = x^+(t)\hspace{5mm}, \hspace{5mm} P_−(t, \sigma) = p_−(t) \tag{1} $$

which is said to be equivalent to $a^+_k=0 \hspace{2mm} \forall k \neq 0$

On these notes, the following Virasoro algebra generator is given :

$$L_N= \frac{1}{2} \sum _{k \in R} \left( \alpha^+ _k \alpha ^- _{n-k} + \alpha^- _k \alpha^+ _{n-k} \right) + \frac{1}{2} \sum \alpha_k \cdot \alpha_{n-k} \tag{2}$$

**and that by applying the gauge conditions we get**

$$L_N= \alpha^+ _0 \alpha^- _n + \frac{1}{2} \sum \alpha_k \cdot \alpha_{n-k} \tag{3}$$

**How does setting that gauge condition turn the first half of (2) into the first half of (3)? (as shown below)**

$$\frac{1}{2} \sum _{k \in R} \left( \alpha^+ _k \alpha ^- _{n-k} + \alpha^- _k \alpha^+ _{n-k} \right) \to  \alpha^+ _0 \alpha^- _n$$

Comment: "Harvard's" notes? You mean those notes are currently used there?

Comment: I was found those notes, which covered some bits mine did not. Is there a problem with them?

Comment: So the question is about zero-modes?

Comment: The question is about ghosts and Virasoro generators

Comment: @user7077252: i mean that those are clearly notes from Paul Townsend's string theory course. Cambridge UK

Comment: My bad, I was an idiot and looked at the link. Thank you

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking for - as you quote, the gauge condition is equivalent to some of the $\alpha_k$ vanishing. How that turns (2) into (3) is rather straightforward. Are you asking why the gauge condition is equivalent to the vanishing of the $\alpha_k$? Have you tried mode expanding the $X$ and $P$ in the gauge conditions?

Comment: I don't understand the transformation you consider quite simple. I know I must be missing something simple, as it doesn't look too complicated, but I can't figure out what.